# How do I return a custom error from a splitn fn?

Tags: rust

I've written this function to parse a comma-separated string and return either a `<Vec<&str>>` or a custom error:

```
fn parse_input(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, ParseError> {
    match s.splitn(2, ',').next() {
        Ok(s) => s.collect::<Vec<&str>>(),
        Err(err) => Err(ParseError::InvalidInput)
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me this response:

```
Ok(s) => s.collect::<Vec<&str>>(),
^^^^^ expected enum `Option`, found enum `Result`

...

Err(err) => Err(ParseError::InvalidInput)
^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Option`, found enum `Result`
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to change the code to satisfy the compiler. What is wrong with this function?

Comment: `.next()` returns an `Option<&str>`, i.e. `Some(s)` or `None`. But what’s `s.collect()` supposed to do? (i.e. what is the overall function supposed to do?)

Comment: I've updated the question with what it's supposed to return, the `s.collect()` is supposed to grab the two parts of the comma-separated string and convert them into a `<Vec<&str>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.next()` returns an `Option<&str>`, i.e. `Some(s)` or `None`.

  ```rust
  fn parse_input(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, ParseError> {
      match s.splitn(2, ',').next() {
          Some(s) => s.collect::<Vec<&str>>(),
          None => Err(ParseError::InvalidInput),
      }
  }
  ```
- Just like you wrapped the error with `Err` to make it a `Result`, the non-error needs to be wrapped with `Ok`.

  ```rust
  fn parse_input(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, ParseError> {
      match s.splitn(2, ',').next() {
          Some(s) => Ok(s.collect::<Vec<&str>>()),
          None => Err(ParseError::InvalidInput),
      }
  }
  ```
- Whether it’s the pattern-matched `Some(s)` or the outer parameter `s`, `s.collect()` doesn’t make sense. Going by your description, maybe you want to split the string on commas, collect that into a `Vec`, and produce an error if the result doesn’t consist of exactly two parts?

  ```rust
  fn parse_input(s: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, ParseError> {
      let parts: Vec<_> = s.split(',').collect();

      if parts.len() == 2 {
          Ok(parts)
      } else {
          Err(ParseError::InvalidInput)
      }
  }
  ```
- Maybe a pair would be better? Also, if more than one comma is acceptable and you just want to split on the first one, [`split_once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_once) fits perfectly.

  ```rust
  fn parse_input(s: &str) -> Result<(&str, &str), ParseError> {
      s.split_once(',').ok_or(ParseError::InvalidInput)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank-you _so much_ for this detailed answer, I didn't quite understand the what I was doing wrong there and your explanation helped _greatly_. Thanks again!